# Using nested for loops to make an array of coordinates (2D array) and incompatible types: int[][] cannot be converted to int[] error

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, return

I'm trying to create an array of coordinates that references the walls(#) in the map. Arrays are a bit confusing to me so I'm not sure if I'm outputting my 2D array as intended. My return statement is giving an unintended compilation error as well. Thanks for the help!

```
public static String[][] map1 = {{"#","D","#"},
                                 {"#","-","#"},
                                 {"#","D","#"}}

public int[] readMap(String[][] map){
   int[][] wallAt = new int[map.length * map[0].length][1];
   for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++){                   
      for(int y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++){            
         if(map[x][y].equals("#")){                     
            wallAt[x][0] = x;                          
            wallAt[x][1] = y;
         }  
         else{                                         
         break;
         }
      }
   }
   return wallAt;                                         
}
```

I expect the output to look something like this:

```
[[0,0]  
 []  
 [0,2]  
 [1,0]  
 []  
 [1,2]  
 [2,0]  
 []  
 [2,2]]
```

I can't currently check the output due to "return wallAt;" having this error:

```
incompatible types: int[][] cannot be converted to int[]
```

I'm not trying to convert to int[] and I'm not sure what's causing the problem. Thank you for pointing out any other errors that I haven't recognized.

Comment: The return type of your method is `int[]`, but you care returning `int[][]`. Change the return type to `int[][]`.

Comment: You've declared `readMap` as returning an `int[]`; you are returning `wallAt` which is an `int[][]`. That is the source of your error.

Comment: wow can't believe I missed that thanks

Comment: I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: `int[][] wallAt = new int[map.length * map[0].length][2];`